# What is the time complexity of nested for loops?

Tags: time-complexity

Case 1

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
   for (j = i; j < n; j++)
```

---

Case 2

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
   for (j = 1; j < i; j++)
```

---

Will there be a difference in the time complexity in big O notation between those two cases?

Answer (score 1):

For theh first case you will have `(n-1)+(n-2)+(n-3)+...+1` iterations. This sum is equal to

```
(n-1)*n/2 = O(n^2).
```

For the second case you will have `n*n` iterations. So in the second case we have `O(n^2)`.

So they are both `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Case 1 and Case 2 running time is exactly similar.

**Case 1:**

[image]

**Case 2:**

[image]